# X.Org and Xserver development headers issue

Tags: 12.04, xorg, sdl

Trying to install SDL2, following the guide [here](http://nothingtocode.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-sdl2-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html).
I've tried this before, and it's destroyed my laptop several times already, because one of the packages (x.org-dev) replaces [*a **lot** of packages*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntaPq.png), and those packages it is replacing are the ones enabling my touchpad to work, it also breaks *lightdm*, it creates an infinite loop at the login screen.
Has anyone been able to compile and install SDL2 correctly, without destroying their distros in the process?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 right now.

Comment: I only have SDL 1.2. What are the commands you use to do that installation? Have you considered installing 13.10 or 14.04 instead of 12.04?

Comment: I get the source code from [here](http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), install the dependencies listed [here](http://nothingtocode.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-sdl2-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html), and use `./configure` then `make` and finally `make install`. Problem is, I never get past step 2 because of the problems described in the OP. Also, I don't use 13.10 or 14.04 because I like my LTS distos, I'm sorta new to everything that isn't ricing here in linux so I rather keep my things as stable as possible.

Comment: Note that 14.04 is an LTS, although you could wait a couple more months to make sure most bugs were taken out... Now, you may want to consider doing this: `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev` to get the headers and libraries to link against. Much easier than recompiling the whole thing. Also in your case the `make install` would probably break. And that's assuming the configure did the right thing.

Comment: To find packages, try things like this one: `apt-cache search libsdl`

Comment: I know about `apt-cache`, but these libraries aren't in the default repos, and so far I haven't been able to find any ppa's or whatever to get the binaries from. I should probably ditch this.

Comment: Ah... I can see `libsdl2-dev` but I'm on 13.10. It could be that 12.04 did not yet have it.

Comment: That would be the problem, maybe I should just make the switch, thanks @AlexisWilke, see ya.